# How to spyOn service call error handling?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I would like to test my controller which makes such service call:

```
myService.get().success(function (data){
   $scope.myData = data;
})
```

I can test this without problem like that:

```
it('should get the accounts', function() {

    spyOn(myService, 'get').and.callFake(function () {
        return {
           success: function(callback) {
              callback(myData);
           }
        }
    });

    expect(myService.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect($scope.myData).toEqual(myData);
})
```

However; if I would like to handle service call error:

```
myService.get().success(function (data){
      $scope.myData = data;
}).catch(function() {
   $scope.error = true;
});
```

My test fails with: Cannot read property 'catch' of undefined

How can I test success and error scenario here using spyOn?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you use jQuery.ajax() to send requests from a service? It provides method `error()`, not `catch()`.